# How to run python program on raspberry pi OS

Tags: python, linux, pip, raspberry-pi

I wrote a python program on my windows and I'm trying to run it on my raspberry pi 3 with Raspberry Pi OS. I am a total beginner and I don't know if / how I have to install the necessary modules. I've also read something about the `sys.path` because of the `idlelib`...

I get this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 2, in <module>
    from idlelib import browser
ImportError: No module named idlelib
```

Python 3.x installed

pip 20.x installed

Comment: You use `pip` to install modules. You could `ssh` into the Pi, then run the `pip` command.

Comment: Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement idlelib (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for idlelib

Comment: It doesn't actually appear to be in the repository. It looks like you'd need to download it from [github](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Lib/idlelib/) and copy the code over, or use `git` or something on the Pi to download it.

Comment: Is the `idlelib` module installed?

Answer (score 0):

As the error states you need to install the idle/idlelib module first to import
it into your code.

For python 3 the command you have to type into the terminal should be:

```
sudo apt-get install idle3
```

Hopefully this solves your problem, if not I would advise you to look into
the installation of idle on your RPI.